# Quickly browse through different available Wireless networks for the iPhone?

Tags: network, wifi, iphone

I was wondering if there is a Cydia App or some other way that provides a way to browse and choose different available networks in a very fast manner ?
I hate going through Settings > Wi-Fi > Network - I would rather have a drop down list from notification center or something similar.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score -1):

As fas as I know, there is only a concept video for Notification Center WiFi seleciton, and there is a Simple Wifi for Notification Center Cydia tweak that will show WiFi info in there, but I don't think there is actually something that gives you exactly what you want.

But really, it's just two taps. Settings icon > WiFi section. That shows you all available networks. If your current WiFi network goes off, a list of available networks will automatically pop up.

Comment: Due to the number of tweaks I have, it really takes a while to go into settings and then wifi. Loading the settings screen takes about 3-5 seconds. Gets really frustrating when you need to keep changing between different WiFi domains.

Comment: If you open Settings and go to WiFi and then exit Settings while leaving it running in the background, that should bring up WiFi straight away next time you go to Settings. But if you're having such problems, maybe you should consider a more "natural" approach than jailbreaking with a bunch of hacks, or use Android which is meant for such customization.

Comment: Not going to use android just to get this feature -.- and I prefer my phone jailbroken, thanks anyway.